# Creating a column that that compares values from one Dataframe to another in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 data frames one employee history and another is a hiring report. What I want is to see if a person's ID, if they are a manager, and in both data frames, and don't have open as a status then Vacant. A a new column **Vacancy** in the first data frame. Below is what the data frames look like:

DF1:

```
ID     ManagerID       Job            Status
 1         3           Sales          Active
 2         3           Sales          Active
 3         10          Sales Manager  Active
 4         5           Tech           Active
 5         12          Tech Manager   Active 
 6         3           Sales          Active
```

DF2:

```
Hiring_ID     Job_Title      Status      # of Roles 
    3         Associate       Open            8
    10        Consultant      Open            3
    10        Lead            Open            1
    7         Advisor         Open            2 
    3         Cashier          NaN            4
```

From here I tried using:

`df['Vacant'] = np.where((df['ID'].isin(df2['Hiring_ID'])) & (df2['Status'].isnull()), 'Yes','No'`

With this code I get no results when I shpuld be getting **ID 3 with Cashiers** as a vancany. Is there a better method then using .isin

This is what Iwith this code am looking for:

```
 ID     Manager_ID        Job            Status        Vacancy
  1          3            Sales          Active           No 
  2          3            Sales          Active           No 
  3          10           Sales Manager  Active           Yes 
  4          5            Tech           Active           No 
  5          12           Tech Manager   Active           No 
  6          3            Sales          Active           No
```

Comment: The logic is unclear to me.

Answer (score 3):

First lets see what your code does by parts:

This part  `df1['ID'].isin(df2['Hiring_ID'])`

gives :

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

and this part `df2['Status'].isnull()` :

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
```

What do you think the & of these give? All Falses right? It is an element-wise & operation.

Now the **answer**:

What you wanted is if there is a match in df2 from df1's ID and also if that status is "NaN" then get those ids and use those ids to update df1. The code will be:

```
ids = df2.loc[df2['Hiring_ID'].isin(df1['ID']) & df2['Status'].isna(), 'Hiring_ID']
df1['Vacancy'] = np.where(df1['ID'].isin(ids), 'Yes', 'No')
print(df1)

   ID  ManagerID            Job  Status Vacancy
0   1          3          Sales  Active      No
1   2          3          Sales  Active      No
2   3         10  Sales Manager  Active     Yes
3   4          5           Tech  Active      No
4   5         12   Tech Manager  Active      No
5   6          3          Sales  Active      No
```